# How to open file using fopen() with public link path param

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel project. I need to generate multiple of pdf files based on pdf template. `setSourceFile()` from FPDI library is needed and have to open the file using `fopen()` with read and write permission. The template file that I used was stored on storage, and can get accessed using public link path.

```
...
$link = Storage::url($file_path);
$input = url($link);
$stream = fopen($input, 'r+', false, stream_context_create());
// "http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/files/template.pdf"
...
```

I did like that, but it takes to long to load the `fopen()`, it responded by error "exceeds the maximum request time". If I hardcoded it using system path, it works. Any idea how I could use `fopen()` with public link path?

Comment: If you're using `php artisan serve` it can only handle one request at a time. You're trying to perform a request from within another request to the same host so it will not work. Try setting up a regular webserver like nginx or apache. For local files I do think it's better to use `public_path('storage/files/template.pdf')` rather than a URL though

Comment: 1. PHP's embedded server cannot serve more than _one_ request at a time, and you're trying to get it to make a second while it's serving the first. 2. Do not make web requests against your own server if you can avoid it, partly for this exact reason [worker exhaustion] but mostly that the web request is a _lot_ of needless overhead and there's most likely a better way to do it. Eg: load the file directly, call the code directly, etc.

Comment: That's make a sense, thx for the tips. I'll fix it. Learn something new today, thx guys

Comment: Yup it works. avoiding using url is the one. @apokryfos. Can you make ur comment as answer?

Comment: @Sammitch thx to you too bro, it was a big point to keeping out too.

Comment: Why not fopen the $file_path instead? Doesn't make any sense for the Laravel app to generate a URL for its own internal access (FPDI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the [public disk](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#the-public-disk) then these files are by default stored in `storage/app/public`. You can then use `php artisan storage:link` to make a symbolic link in `public/storage` to make them accessible over the internet. However to access them within your own application it's not necessary (or even a good idea) to access them via a URL. If you don't provide a loopback link then the request will have to do a DNS name resolution over the internet which adds overhead. In addition if you are using `php artisan serve` only one request at a time can be fulfilled so starting a new request from within an existing request will prevent the new request from being fulfilled.

Instead you can use the paths specified in the documentation to access the files locally e.g. using one of:

```
storage_path('files/template.pdf') 
// Or
public_path('storage/files/template.pdf')
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot for me understanding laravel